# Mountroot Prompt while installing freebsd 10.3

Tags: linux, mount, freebsd

I am installing free bsd on intel's minnowboard using bootable sdcard. But during installation I got mountroot prompt. I have tried using ? option but No GEOM managed disk devices are shown.